# Hashing a text file

Tags: python, security, authentication, hash, registration

I am trying to create a registration and login application in python with TKINTER. I have a working program although it is not at all secure as user details are stored in a text file, I figured the best way to make it more secure would be to hash the file. I've been trying and trying, but I cannot manage to do it, how might I go about this, and what is the issue I am having?

```
import os
from tkinter import *
import hashlib

def delete2():
screen3.destroy()


def delete3():
screen4.destroy()


def delete4():
screen5.destroy()


def login_success():
global screen3
screen3 = Toplevel(screen)
screen3.title("Success!")
screen3.geometry("150x100")
Label(screen3, text="Login Success!").pack()
Button(screen3, text="OK", command=delete2).pack()


def invalid_credentials():
global screen4
screen4 = Toplevel(screen)
screen4.title("Invalid password or secret")
screen4.geometry("150x100")
Label(screen4, text="Invalid credentials!").pack()
Button(screen4, text="OK", command=delete3).pack()


def user_not_found():
global screen5
screen5 = Toplevel(screen)
screen5.title("User not found")
screen5.geometry("150x100")
Label(screen5, text="User not found").pack()
Button(screen5, text="OK", command=delete4).pack()


def register_user():
print("Working")
username_info = username.get()
password_info = password.get()
secret_info = secret.get()

password_info.encode()
username_info.encode()

# find a better way to save files, TXT is not at all secure
File = open(username_info, "w")
File.write(username_info + "\n")
File.write(password_info + "\n")
File.write(secret_info)
File.close()

#File = (username_info+".txt")
#BLOCK_SIZE = 65536

#file_hash = hashlib.sha256()
#with open(File, "rb")as f:
 #   fb = f.read(BLOCK_SIZE)
  #  while len(fb) > 0:
   #     file_hash.update(fb)
    #    fb = f.read(BLOCK_SIZE)

#print(file_hash.hexdigest())

username_entry.delete(0, END)
password_entry.delete(0, END)
secret_entry.delete(0, END)

Label(screen1, text="Registration Successful", fg="green", font=("calibri", 11)).pack()


def login_verify():
username1 = username_verify.get()
password1 = password_verify.get()
secret1 = secret_verify.get()
username_entry1.delete(0, END)
password_entry1.delete(0, END)
secret_entry1.delete(0, END)

list_of_files = os.listdir()
if username1 in list_of_files:
    file1 = open(username1, "r")
    verify = file1.read().splitlines()
    if password1 in verify:
        print("")
        if secret1 in verify:
            login_success()
        else:
            invalid_credentials()
    else:
        invalid_credentials()


else:
    user_not_found()


def register():
global screen1
screen1 = Toplevel(screen)
screen1.title("Register")
screen1.geometry("350x250")

global username
global password
global secret
global username_entry
global password_entry
global secret_entry

username = StringVar()
password = StringVar()
secret = StringVar()
private_key = StringVar()

# buttons for registration screen1
Label(screen1, text="Please enter details below * ").pack()
Label(screen1, text="").pack()

Label(screen1, text="Username * ").pack()
username_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable=username)
username_entry.pack()

# Label(screen1, text="Password * ").pack()
# password_entry = Entry(screen1, show="*", textvariable=password)
# password_entry.pack()

Label(screen1, text="Password * ").pack()
password_entry = Entry(screen1, show="*", textvariable=password)
password_entry.pack()

Label(screen1, text="Shared Secret * ").pack()
secret_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable=secret)
secret_entry.pack()
Label(screen1, text="").pack()
Button(screen1, text="Register", width="10", height="1", command=register_user).pack()

# Possibly do in new .py


def login():
global screen2
screen2 = Toplevel(screen)
screen2.title("Login")
screen2.geometry("300x250")
Label(screen2, text="Please enter details below to login").pack()
Label(screen2, text="").pack()

global username_verify
global password_verify
global secret_verify
username_verify = StringVar()
password_verify = StringVar()
secret_verify = StringVar()

global username_entry1
global password_entry1
global secret_entry1

Label(screen2, text="Username * ").pack()
username_entry1 = Entry(screen2, textvariable=username_verify)
username_entry1.pack()
Label(screen2, text="").pack()
Label(screen2, text="Password * ").pack()
password_entry1 = Entry(screen2, show="*", textvariable=password_verify)
password_entry1.pack()
Label(screen2, text="").pack()
Label(screen2, text="Shared Secret * ").pack()
secret_entry1 = Entry(screen2, textvariable=secret_verify)
secret_entry1.pack()
Label(screen2, text="").pack()
Button(screen2, text="Login", width=10, height=1, command=login_verify).pack()


def main_screen():
global screen
screen = Tk()
# Screen size, title, font and login and register buttons
screen.geometry("300x250")
screen.title("PassWordProject")
Label(text="PassWordProject", bg="grey", width="300", height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack()
Label(text="").pack()
Button(text="Login", height="2", width="30", command=login).pack()
Label(text="").pack()
Button(text="Register", height="2", width="30", command=register).pack()

screen.mainloop()


main_screen()
```

Comment: if you will hash your file you won't be aable to read it as plain text anymore, most of the time server hash the password to protect the user password in a case of server attack. we do it just for the password because we don't need to read never, we just need to hash the pass the user try to login with and compair it to the hashed password we stored.

Comment: So don't hash the entire file? but just the password, this is something i've tried but constantly struggled with as I get errors. The errors include the fact that I can't encode the user input for password, I think this is because i've used - Entry(screen1, show="*", textvariable=password) - which doesn't allow for encoding like if I was to use input("password").encode. I'm sorry if what i've understood/ said is incorrect, I am very much a novice programmer. Thank you for your help